What happened to MOSBD?
There was a time around 2008 when TI and Toshiba annouced new MOSBD aka FETKEYs. These MOSFETs come with an internal Schottky Diode to reduce free wheeling loss during dead time. See Toshiba Mosfet Guide 2009 on page 18 (23).
It appears that these MOSBDs have disappeared. Didn't they hold what they promised?
Wouldn't they solve the reverse recovery issue when used as a synchronous buck rectifier?

What does ONSEMI say?

TOSHIBA seemed to have continued to develop SiC MOSFET with Embedded Schottky Barrier Diode (SBD) products. From a 2022 press release:

KAWASAKI, Japan--(BUSINESS WIRE)-- Toshiba Electronic Devices & Storage Corporation and Toshiba Corporation (collectively “Toshiba”) have developed an SiC metal oxide semiconductor field effect transistor (MOSFET) that arranges embedded Schottky barrier diodes (SBD) in a check pattern (check-pattern embedded SBD) to realize both low on-resistance and high reliability. Toshiba has confirmed that the design secures an approximately 20% reduction in on-resistance (RonA) against its current SiC MOSFET, with no loss of reliability.


The 3rd generation SiC MOSFETs that contributes to lower loss of power supply in application article contains:

Therefore, our 3rd generation SiC MOSFETs have the following features.

Built-in Schottky barrier diode (SBD) reduced the forward voltage VDSF , and suppresses fluctuation in on-resistance RDS(ON)


I.e. there have now been 3 generations of products.
From the TW015N120C datasheet:

Features:

Chip design of 3rd generation (Built-in SiC schottky barrier diode)
Low diode forward voltage: VDSF = -1.35 V (typ.)
High voltage: VDSS = 1200 V


The TOSHIBA Selection Guide 2024 MOSFETs section 3. MOSFET with Diode has 9 devices, so appears to be an active product range.
